How can I transfer SOL to an account on the command line?
I created a token account and token on Solana (Used Solana CLI and powershell). Send to that account SOL (more then actually need) and now I want to transfer it back to my wallet but I only can transfer my new created token but not SOL token. How to transfer SOL from account (I can't do it from phantom and solflare wallet).
I try to transfer token from wallets but it doesn't see SOL token on account and use command spl-token transfer.

SOL is the native token of Solana - it's not an SPL token. To transfer SOL, use the solana command, not the spl-token command.
solana transfer --from <KEYPAIR> <RECIPIENT_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> <AMOUNT> --fee-payer <KEYPAIR>

See the Solana Labs docs
